# Why does "auto" declare strings as const char* instead of std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, auto

I made a template which adds the data it is given. If I use it like this, the compiler declares in_1 and in_2 as const char *, and the code doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T addstuff(T part_1, T part_2){
    return(part_1+part_2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto in_1="Shut ";
    auto in_2="up.";
    cout<<addstuff(in_1, in_2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I declare in_1 and in_2 std::string, it works like a charm.

Why can't (or doesn't) the compiler declare those strings automatically std::string?

Comment: Why would it? Their type is not `std::string` but `const char (&)[N + 1]` (N is the length of the string).

Comment: This is why we need string literals (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s). A confused question, but it shows how far expectations on C++ have come (and how beginner friendly it can be).

Comment: For what it's worth: You can implement the string literal suffix yourself as _s in C++11; no need to wait. `std::string operator"" _s(const char * str, size_t len) { return std::string{str, len}; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't "write" to your auto variable is that it's a const char * or const char [1], because that is the type of any string constant.

The point of auto is to resolve to the simplest possible type which "works" for the type of the assignment. The compiler does not "look forward to see what you are doing with the variable", so it doesn't understand that later on you will want to write into this variable, and use it to store a string, so std::string would make more sense.

You code could be made to work in many different ways, here's one that makes some sense:

```
std::string default_name = "";
auto name = default_name;

cin >> name;
```

Comment: You might want to change "string constant" to "string literal" in the first paragraph, because a string constant might be reasonably understood as a constant `std::string`.

Answer (score 7):

If you use string literals, `auto` will work as expected.

In C++14, C++17 or C++20, you can place an `s` after the quotes, and it will create a `std::string` instead of a `const char*` string.

This can be used together with `auto` to create a `std::string`:

```
auto hello = "hello"s;
```

String literals are not enabled by default. One way of enabling string literals is to place the following at the top of the source file:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
```

As an example, this loop works for `std::string` (with `s` added to the string literal), but not for `const char*` type string literals:

```
for (auto &x : hello) {                                                                        
    std::cout << "letter: " << x << std::endl;                                                         
}
```

Here is the cppreference page for [the ""s operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Answer (score 4):

Because string literals have type `const char[N+1]`, not `std::string`.

This is just a fact of the language.

They could have made it so that `auto` has a special case for string literals, but that would be inconsistent, surprising and of very little benefit.

Comment: It'd be good if this answer also explained why `in_1` does not have type `const char[6]`

Answer (score 0):

`auto` will declare the variable as the compile-time type of the expression you initialize it to.

String literals are of type `const char*`, not `std::string`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Without the reference.

Comment: To be precise, string literals are of type `const char [length + 1]`, but they of course decay into a pointer.